# Meaning of the sentence with emphasis on the bold phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Consider:

> His advisers, such as Dominic Cummings, had a proclivity for honesty **bordering on the suicidal.**- *the Guardian*   ---

How does the phrase in the bold affect the meaning of the sentence as a whole? As far as I could deduce, it means that Dominic Cummings, was inclined to being  honest even if it proved disastrous to him, but is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding of the sentence is correct.

Comment: move to comment may be?